# std::next_permutation() from a part of vector

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, permutation

i'm trying to generate permutations from a part of a vector. See below.

```
vector<int> myArray;
myArray.resize(5);
myArray[0] = 1;
myArray[1] = 2;
myArray[2] = 3;
myArray[3] = 4;
myArray[4] = 5;
int i = 0;

do {
    for (i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
        printf("%i ", myArray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
} while (next_permutation(myArray.at(1), myArray.at(3)));
```

I need to generate permutations only between positions 1 and 3. Unfortunately `vector::at()` is returning reference, but `next_permutation()` needs `BidirectionalIterator` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while (next_permutation(myArray.begin()+1, myArray.begin()+3));` should work